# Meteor: this.userId and Meteor.userId() both are null within a Meteor Method

Tags: javascript, meteor

To boil down this issue to the basic problem and a minimum of code, I've created a plain new meteor app, added the `accounts-password` package and added the following code snippet. There's a test user in my database.

```js
Meteor.methods({
    'testMethod': function() {
        console.log('test2:', this.userId); // => null
        console.log('test3:', Meteor.userId()); // => null
    }
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('testPublication', function() {
        console.log('test1:', this.userId); // => 1c8tHy3zb8vP9E5yb
        Meteor.call('testMethod');
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.loginWithPassword('test', 'test', function() {
        Meteor.subscribe('testPublication');
    });
}
```

As you can see, within the publication `this.userId` contains the correct userId. But within the Meteor Method `testMethod` both `this.userId` and `Meteor.userId()` are returning `null`.

Is this a meteor bug or is this approach wrong?

Comment: It looks like your method is In the global scope from your snippet provided. this.userId only works on the server (as I'm sure you know), which would also cause the nested Meteor.userId() to fail.

Comment: Publications are executed on the server, this is actually the problem here according to the current answers.

Comment: That is correct publish => server, subscribe => client. Method => server, call => client || server

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After lots of discussions and some answers, it seems like Meteor Methods are not intended to be called from the server side and the userId is simply not available if not called from the client side. Despite this is not helpful at all and a counter intuitive behavior of the framework, it's the way Meteor works.

However there's a package called `meteor-user-extra` (https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-user-extra) which makes `Meteor.userId()` work also inside the publish endpoint functions and solved my problem.

Comment: I already told you how to do it without a package... Just pass the id to the call inside the publish and it should work even though it is NOT how you should do it. Meteor.call('methodName', this.userId) in the publish should work. I already explained this to you and why its not working.

Comment: Besides, Meteor.userId() WORKS in the server side methods. Just not in the publications.

Comment: As I mentioned, there are cases (astronomy events) where passing the id is not possible.

Comment: Meteor methods are very well intended to be called server side. If they are, the `connection` is simply `null`. Why? Because there is none! It was called from the server. Without a `connection`. What you fail to understand is that if a function call originates on the server, it is simply illogical to try and associate it with any userId. It has nothing to do with Meteor being a framework.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior. It is because you are calling the method from the server. There is no user on the server hence the userId on the method invocation obejct (`this`) is `null`. Try calling it from the client when you are logged in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this behavior is not intuitive. There is a user and it should be possible to work with the user on the server side. I found this issue by writing a astronomy event (see https://github.com/jagi/meteor-astronomy/issues/488). What's the intended way in meteor to work with the current logged in user on the server side if this is the expected behavior?

Comment: why not simply pass userId from publications to method?

Comment: It's ugly. And I expect from an framework, that it does this work for me. Just every other framework does.

Comment: @phortx Dude, you are missing the point. There could be 1000s of users connected to the server at the same time. So there is no way to associate the call to a specific user if it originates on the server. You see?

Comment: Actually not. In the concrete runtime of the method/function the user is determined due the fact the actual request is triggered by a concrete user.

Comment: @phortx Methods designed to be called from client, it is inapropriate way to use them like some kind of global functions.

Comment: That's something I understand and that sounds legit even they're used like that.

Comment: @phortx When you wrap the code calling the method in an isServer block then the method call is not triggered by a user. This code is exclusively executed on the server. Nowhere else.

Comment: @phortx Please consider accepting my answer since it is the appropriate answer to your question.

Comment: I've added an answer by myself with a solution, that works, I'll accept that in 2 days. However your answer is correct and I've upvoted it. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you don't return a response from the server to your client side. This is how you do it:

```
methodName: function (arg1, arg2){
    //do something with the arguements, maybe throw an error:
    if(!Meteor.user()){
        //it won't do anything after the error so you don't have to write an else statement
        throw new Meteor.Error('You are not a user!');
    }

    return Meteor.userId()
},
```

and your call in the **client side**:

```
Meteor.call('methodName', arg1, arg2, function(err, res){
    if(err){
        //err is the error you throw in the method
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        //result is what you return from your method
        console.log(res)
    }
});
```

The `Meteor.userId()` works perfectly in methods or client side, out of the box.

Additionally, publish can only return a cursor to the client side as far as I remember. You can't even return an object you find with `findOne()`.

**EDIT**:

You are calling a method from the server publication without passing any arguements. If you call a method from the client side, from a user account, it won't come back as null or even though I believe it is wrong, it might also work if you pass this.userId as an arguement to your current `.call()` in your publish but it will **still** not give you Meteor.userId() in the method. It will return you the arguement/id you pass from the publish.

Comment: This isn't the issue. Maybe you misunderstood the question :) The Meteor Method is called. The problem is that the userId is null.

Comment: @phortx can you try it in your browser console please? not this.userId, try Meteor.userId()

Comment: Sure. It returns the userId as expected and just like within the publish function as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thank you. As I mentioned in my comment of the other answer this is pretty unintuitive ... However I stumbled upon this issue in a more complex case: An astronomy event where I need the user. Take a look at https://github.com/jagi/meteor-astronomy/issues/488 - Do you have any advice here? Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: @phortx Can you please briefly explain what you want to do? Publish something that belongs to current user only? I'll write an example of it as pub/sub/methods are pretty easy to use and no tricks needed AFAIK

Comment: I'd like to automate filtering and maintaining a companyId field in nearly all of my astronomy models by adding events for beforeFind and beforeUpdate. I DONT want the developer to manually filter by companyId in each publication due the potential for data leaks. The fact, that the userId (which gives me the user and the companyId) is often not available on the server side makes it hard to implement that.

Comment: What do you mean by manually filter by companyid? you write the code once and it works for every company/user. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: You write the code once, but maybe buggy. If you have about 200 different publications, it's easy to forget to filter by companyId once and have data published which should be visible to the user. In order to have single point of failure I want to have the filtering by the companyId done by the model.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function testMethod() {
    console.log('test2:', this.userId); // => should be 1c8tHy3zb8vP9E5yb
}

Meteor.methods({
    'testMethod': testMethod
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('testPublication', function() {
        console.log('test1:', this.userId); // => 1c8tHy3zb8vP9E5yb
        testMethod.call(this);
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.loginWithPassword('test', 'test', function() {
        Meteor.subscribe('testPublication');
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In methods,replace

```
 console.log('test2:', this.userId); // => null
 console.log('test3:', Meteor.userId()); // => null
```

With

```
if(Meteor.user)    //USE THIS!
 {
 console.log('test2:', Meteor.userId()); // => null
 console.log('test3:', Meteor.userId()); // => null

 }
```

this.userid won't work in methods. However, using Meteor.userId return the id of the user who invoked the method call.

Comment: Ehm ... you see that the lines in code you posted are identical? And both return null? And both were included in my original code?

Comment: If you see the 'if' statement where we check the existence of userid, it will not return null.

Comment: Made it 'more visible' with comment. `//USE THIS`

Comment: That doesn't change anything. `Meteor.userId()` is still `null`

Comment: your user is logged in right?  It it `undefined` or `null`

Comment: The user is logged in. In the publication `this.userId` returns the correct userId.

Comment: Strange. This technique works perfectly for me though. A solution will be to pass the id as a parameter to the function.

Comment: As mentioned in another thread, this is not a option. However `Metor.user` is a function btw. If I change your snippet to a function call, the console.log calls are omitted, which is what I was expecting, since it seems like there is not information about the logged in user in a meteor method.

Comment: @phortx there is information in logged in user in methods if you call from client side. You're calling a method from server without passing an arguement.